# While posting model object, date properties having 'dd-MM-yyyy' value

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, .net-7.0, abp, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm facing an issue, in aspnetboilerplate ASP.NET Core 7.

While posting a model object with a date value having `'dd-MM-yyyy'` format.

I've tried many options but was unable to resolve the issue.
if someone has the thought how we can handle it? globalized way.

I've set `CultureInfo` but still that error occurs.